# Browse all OPC.UA Tags within a Node automatically

Tags: c#, opc, opc-ua

I have downloaded the source code from http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-.NETStandard/ and I am slowly getting to grips with it. I found this code on this forum and it works great.

But I am wondering if it is possible to browse to and automatically add all the Tags within the OPC UA Servers tree and check the values of each tag recursively every x amount of minutes

In the example below I have to add the Tags Manually to a taglist

```
    //creating a object that encapsulates the netire OPC UA Server related work
    OPCUAClass myOPCUAServer;

    //creating a dictionary of Tags that would be captured from the OPC UA Server
    Dictionary<String, Form1.OPCUAClass.TagClass> TagList = new Dictionary<String, Form1.OPCUAClass.TagClass>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Add tags to the Tag List, For each tag, you have to define the name of the tag and its address
        //the address can typically be found by browsing the OPC UA Server's tree. In the example below
        // The OPC Server had the following hierarchy: Production_CAMS_AMMS -> L4_AMMS_Audit_Station_02 -> AMMSDQ 
        //i used AntAttributeMax01 as a name of the tag, you can use any name
        //add as many tags as you want to capture
        TagList.Add("test", new Form1.OPCUAClass.TagClass("test", "Production_CAMS_AMMS.L4_AMMS_Audit_Station_02.AMMSDQ.test"));

        //to initialize the OPC UA Server, provide the IP Address, Port Number, the list of tags you want to capture
        //in some OPC UA servers and kepware aswell the session can be closed by the OPC UA Server, so its better to 
        //allow the class to reinitiate session periodically, before renewing current sessions are closed
        myOPCUAServer = new OPCUAClass("127.0.0.1", "49320", TagList, true, 1, "2");


        //once the OPC Server has been initialized, you can easily read Tag values and even see when they were
        // updated last time
        //as an example i could read the TBC0401 tag by:

        var tagCurrentValue = TagList["test"].CurrentValue;
        var tagLastGoodValue = TagList["test"].LastGoodValue;
        var lastTimeTagupdated = TagList["test"].LastUpdatedTime;
    }
```

This works great and every time a value is changed on the tag it will print the value but I am hoping that there is a way that you can browse the OPC SERVER Tree from my code and add the tags automatically and than check the values of each Tag every x amount of minutes. Here is the full code for reference

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Opc.Ua;   // Install-Package OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua
using Opc.Ua.Client;
using Opc.Ua.Configuration;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace opctesting
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    //creating a object that encapsulates the netire OPC UA Server related work
    OPCUAClass myOPCUAServer;

    //creating a dictionary of Tags that would be captured from the OPC UA Server
    Dictionary<String, Form1.OPCUAClass.TagClass> TagList = new Dictionary<String, Form1.OPCUAClass.TagClass>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Add tags to the Tag List, For each tag, you have to define the name of the tag and its address
        //the address can typically be found by browsing the OPC UA Server's tree. In the example below
        // The OPC Server had the following hierarchy: Production_CAMS_AMMS -> L4_AMMS_Audit_Station_02 -> AMMSDQ 
        //i used AntAttributeMax01 as a name of the tag, you can use any name
        //add as many tags as you want to capture
        TagList.Add("test", new Form1.OPCUAClass.TagClass("test", "Production_CAMS_AMMS.L4_AMMS_Audit_Station_02.AMMSDQ.test"));

        //to initialize the OPC UA Server, provide the IP Address, Port Number, the list of tags you want to capture
        //in some OPC UA servers and kepware aswell the session can be closed by the OPC UA Server, so its better to 
        //allow the class to reinitiate session periodically, before renewing current sessions are closed
        myOPCUAServer = new OPCUAClass("127.0.0.1", "49320", TagList, true, 1, "2");


        //once the OPC Server has been initialized, you can easily read Tag values and even see when they were
        // updated last time
        //as an example i could read the TBC0401 tag by:

        var tagCurrentValue = TagList["test"].CurrentValue;
        var tagLastGoodValue = TagList["test"].LastGoodValue;
        var lastTimeTagupdated = TagList["test"].LastUpdatedTime;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public class OPCUAClass
    {
        public string ServerAddress { get; set; }
        public string ServerPortNumber { get; set; }
        public bool SecurityEnabled { get; set; }
        public string MyApplicationName { get; set; }
        public Session OPCSession { get; set; }
        public string OPCNameSpace { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, TagClass> TagList { get; set; }

        public bool SessionRenewalRequired { get; set; }
        public double SessionRenewalPeriodMins { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastTimeSessionRenewed { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastTimeOPCServerFoundAlive { get; set; }
        public bool ClassDisposing { get; set; }
        public bool InitialisationCompleted { get; set; }
        private Thread RenewerTHread { get; set; }
        public OPCUAClass(string serverAddres, string serverport, Dictionary<string, TagClass> taglist, bool sessionrenewalRequired, double sessionRenewalMinutes, string nameSpace)
        {
            ServerAddress = serverAddres;
            ServerPortNumber = serverport;
            MyApplicationName = "Kepware.KEPserver.V6";
            TagList = taglist;
            SessionRenewalRequired = sessionrenewalRequired;
            SessionRenewalPeriodMins = sessionRenewalMinutes;
            OPCNameSpace = nameSpace;
            LastTimeOPCServerFoundAlive = DateTime.Now;
            InitializeOPCUAClient();

            if (SessionRenewalRequired)
            {
                LastTimeSessionRenewed = DateTime.Now;
                RenewerTHread = new Thread(renewSessionThread);
                RenewerTHread.Start();
            }
        }

        //class destructor
        ~OPCUAClass()
        {

            ClassDisposing = true;
            try
            {

                OPCSession.Close();
                OPCSession.Dispose();
                OPCSession = null;
                RenewerTHread.Abort();
            }
            catch { }

        }

        private void renewSessionThread()
        {
            while (!ClassDisposing)
            {
                if ((DateTime.Now - LastTimeSessionRenewed).TotalMinutes > SessionRenewalPeriodMins
                    || (DateTime.Now - LastTimeOPCServerFoundAlive).TotalSeconds > 60)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Renewing Session");
                    try
                    {
                        OPCSession.Close();
                        OPCSession.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch { }
                    InitializeOPCUAClient();
                    LastTimeSessionRenewed = DateTime.Now;

                }
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

            }

        }
        public void InitializeOPCUAClient()
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Step 1 - Create application configuration and certificate.");
            var config = new ApplicationConfiguration()    //Opc.ua namespace
            {
                ApplicationName = MyApplicationName,
                ApplicationUri = Utils.Format(@"urn:{0}:" + MyApplicationName + "", ServerAddress),
                ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
                SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration
                {
                    ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault", SubjectName = Utils.Format(@"CN={0}, DC={1}", MyApplicationName, ServerAddress) },
                    TrustedIssuerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Certificate Authorities" },
                    TrustedPeerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications" },
                    RejectedCertificateStore = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates" },
                    AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates = true,
                    AddAppCertToTrustedStore = true
                },
                TransportConfigurations = new TransportConfigurationCollection(),
                TransportQuotas = new TransportQuotas { OperationTimeout = 15000 },
                ClientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration { DefaultSessionTimeout = 60000 },
                TraceConfiguration = new TraceConfiguration()
            };
            config.Validate(ApplicationType.Client).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (config.SecurityConfiguration.AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates)
            {
                config.CertificateValidator.CertificateValidation += (s, e) => { e.Accept = (e.Error.StatusCode == StatusCodes.BadCertificateUntrusted); };
            }

            var application = new ApplicationInstance
            {
                ApplicationName = MyApplicationName,
                ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
                ApplicationConfiguration = config
            };
            application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 2048).GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            //string serverAddress = Dns.GetHostName();
            string serverAddress = ServerAddress; ;
            var selectedEndpoint = CoreClientUtils.SelectEndpoint("opc.tcp://" + serverAddress + ":" + ServerPortNumber + "", useSecurity: SecurityEnabled, operationTimeout: 15000);

            // Console.WriteLine($"Step 2 - Create a session with your server: {selectedEndpoint.EndpointUrl} ");
            // All UA communications are done through sessions,
            Console.WriteLine($"Step 2 - Create a session with your server: {selectedEndpoint.EndpointUrl} ");
            using (var session = Session.Create(config, new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, selectedEndpoint, EndpointConfiguration.Create(config)), false, "", 60000, null, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Step 3 - Browse the server namespace.");
                ReferenceDescriptionCollection refs;
                Byte[] cp;
                session.Browse(null, null, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out cp, out refs);
                Console.WriteLine("DisplayName: BrowseName, NodeClass");
                foreach (var rd in refs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}", rd.DisplayName, rd.BrowseName, rd.NodeClass);
                    ReferenceDescriptionCollection nextRefs;
                    byte[] nextCp;
                    session.Browse(null, null, ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(rd.NodeId, session.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out nextCp, out nextRefs);
                    foreach (var nextRd in nextRefs)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("+ {0}: {1}, {2}", nextRd.DisplayName, nextRd.BrowseName, nextRd.NodeClass);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Step 4 - Create a subscription. Set a faster publishing interval if you wish.");
                var subscription = new Subscription(session.DefaultSubscription) { PublishingInterval = 1000 };

                Console.WriteLine("Step 5 - Add a list of items you wish to monitor to the subscription.");
                var list = new List<MonitoredItem> { new MonitoredItem(subscription.DefaultItem) { DisplayName = "ServerStatusCurrentTime", StartNodeId = "i=2258" } };
                list.ForEach(i => i.Notification += OnTagValueChange);
                subscription.AddItems(list);

                Console.WriteLine("Step 6 - Add the subscription to the session.");
                session.AddSubscription(subscription);
                subscription.Create();


            }
        }


        public class TagClass
        {

            public TagClass(string displayName, string nodeID)
            {
                DisplayName = displayName;
                NodeID = nodeID;

            }

            public DateTime LastUpdatedTime { get; set; }

            public DateTime LastSourceTimeStamp { get; set; }


            public string StatusCode { get; set; }

            public string LastGoodValue { get; set; }
            public string CurrentValue { get; set; }
            public string NodeID { get; set; }

            public string DisplayName { get; set; }


        }
        public void OnTagValueChange(MonitoredItem item, MonitoredItemNotificationEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (var value in item.DequeueValues())
            {

                if (item.DisplayName == "ServerStatusCurrentTime")
                {
                    LastTimeOPCServerFoundAlive = value.SourceTimestamp.ToLocalTime();

                }
                else
                {
                    if (value.Value != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}", item.DisplayName, value.Value.ToString(), value.SourceTimestamp.ToLocalTime(), value.StatusCode);
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}", item.DisplayName, "Null Value", value.SourceTimestamp, value.StatusCode);

                    if (TagList.ContainsKey(item.DisplayName))
                    {
                        if (value.Value != null)
                        {
                            TagList[item.DisplayName].LastGoodValue = value.Value.ToString();
                            TagList[item.DisplayName].CurrentValue = value.Value.ToString();
                            TagList[item.DisplayName].LastUpdatedTime = DateTime.Now;
                            TagList[item.DisplayName].LastSourceTimeStamp = value.SourceTimestamp.ToLocalTime();
                            TagList[item.DisplayName].StatusCode = value.StatusCode.ToString();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TagList[item.DisplayName].StatusCode = value.StatusCode.ToString();
                            TagList[item.DisplayName].CurrentValue = null;

                        }

                    }

                }

            }
            InitialisationCompleted = true;
        }

    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Typically, you want to use subscriptions to monitor changes in variables. But you will still monitor each variable individually and find them by browsing.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I only manage to browse one level of the server and only get this list:  
        ServerArray (Variable)
        NamespaceArray (Variable)
        ServerStatus (Variable)
        ServiceLevel (Variable)
        Auditing (Variable)
        EstimatedReturnTime (Variable)
        LocalTime (Variable)
        ServerCapabilities (Object)
        ServerDiagnostics (Object)
        VendorServerInfo (Object)
        ServerRedundancy (Object)
        Namespaces (Object)
        ServerConfiguration (Object)
        Dictionaries (Object)....